# Get list of values for factor in R

Tags: r

I would like to convert values of factor into a list, how can i do it?
P.S.: Sry, Im new to R

Example: i have the following factor:

```
> table(v)
v
       (0,80]      (80,500]    (500,1000]  (1000,10000] (10000,90000] 
         8259          2167           112            62             1
```

how can i get:

```
 c(8259,2167,112,62,1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `unname()`:

```
x <- table(cut(runif(100), 5))
x


(0.00448,0.202]   (0.202,0.399]   (0.399,0.596]   (0.596,0.794] 
             24              23              16              19 
  (0.794,0.991] 
             18 


unname(x)
[1] 24 23 16 19 18
```

Answer (score 3):

You can transform the result of table to a data.frame and:

```
as.data.frame(x)$Freq
[1] 28 13 20 20 19
```

Answer (score 3):

Or:

```
test <- as.vector(table(v)[])
test
```